# Delete multiple AMI through CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, snapshot, amazon-ami

How can I delete more than thousands of AMIs and snapshots in AWS for linux servers?
Is it possible to delete AMIs that were created in a specific year, for example, all AMIs created in 2020?

if i can get a solution, it will be great.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and explain why it does not work.

Comment: I haven't tried yet .please suggest .

Answer (score 1):

This process is probably easier to do when using a programming language (eg Python) that using the AWS CLI, but if you are skilled in shell script then you can probably figure it out.

I'll give examples using boto3, but there are equivalents in the AWS CLI.

You can use [`describe_images()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_images.html) to list the AMIs in your AWS Account. Make sure you use `Owners=['self']` to only return AMIs that were created in your AWS Account. Failing to do this will list *ALL* AMIs in the region, including ones you didn't create.

You can specify `filters` when calling `list_images()` and pass a value for `creation-date` (that can include a wildcard, eg `2020*`).

When you find one that you wish to delete, you can use [`deregister_image()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/deregister_image.html) to make the AMI disappear. It is possible that the underlying Snapshot for the AMI still exists, so you might separately need to list and delete the Amazon EBS Snapshots that were used by the AMIs.

You would need to write your own program that obtains a list of images (as shown above) and then decides which ones to delete.